# Can we find a holomorphic representative in an equivalence class?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSU{PSU}$Let $U\subseteq \mathbb C^2$ be a given open set, $A$ be the set composed by maps (not necessarily continuous) $f:U\to \PSL(2,\mathbb C)$. We call $f_1,f_2\in A$ equivalent if the image of $f_1f_2^{-1} : x \mapsto f_1(x)f_2(x)^{-1}$ is contained in $\PSU(2,\mathbb C)$.

Then we consider such a $g(z_1,z_2)\in A$. If there are $g_1$, $g_2$ equivalent to $g$ such that $g_i(z_1,z_2)$ is holomophic in the $i$th coordinate ($i=1,2$), can we find a holomorphic map $h$ equivalent to $g$?

For a easier case  when PSL2 and PSU2 are replaced with C and R: I have following caculation.

Let $f:\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C$ be a map.If there is  a map $\varphi:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y_i}$, $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y_i}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y_i}$ for $i=1,2$, then $f-\varphi$ is holomorphic. The differential of $\varphi$ is completely decided by $f$

The condition tells us that for fixed $i$, there is $\varphi_i:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\frac{\partial \varphi_i}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y_i}$, $\frac{\partial \varphi_i}{\partial y_i}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y_i}$. we have $\varphi_1(z_1,z_2)=\varphi_1(0,z_2)+\int_\gamma D\varphi_1 dz_1$. Thus $\varphi_1$ is uniquely decided by $\varphi_1(0,z_2)$. As a result, $\varphi$ is uniquely decided by $\varphi(0,z_2)$ which is uniquely decided by $\varphi(0,0)$. We may assume that $\varphi(0,0)=0$ and the only possible $\varphi$ is given by $\varphi(z_1,z_2)=\int_{\gamma_1}D\varphi_2(0,z_2)d z_2+\int_{\gamma_2}D\varphi_1(z_1,z_2)dz_1$. But $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial x_2}+\int something$. So there is no $\varphi$ unless $f$ is choosen to be "very good" such that the intergration term is $0$

If my deduction is correct, will it work similarly for the $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$ case?

Comment: How do you define $f_1-f_2$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I should use $f_1 f_2^{-1}$ instead of $f_1-f_2$. I want to say that for any $x\in U$, the product $f_1(x) f_2(x)^{-1}$ is contained in $PSU(2,\mathbb C)$

Comment: To fix ideas, do you know the answer when $PSL_2$ and $PSU_2$ are replaced with $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: I tried to solve your cases and get a negative answer. Does it work for the original case ?

Comment: I don't know. This is an analogy, since locally $PSU_2$ in $PSL_2(C)$ somewhat looks like $\mathbf{R}^3$ in $\mathbf{C}^3$. In particular, if there is a "local" obstruction, it might work too in this setting.